# how to solve same dpi problem with different screen size

Tags: android

my phone is galaxy s9  that is 5.8 inch and xxhdpi. And my virtual test phone is nexus 5 that is xxhdpi but the screen size is 4.95 inch. The imageview from the Galaxy S9 appears to be cut off from the Nexus 5. Layout-xxhdpi applies to the same device, with some looking right and some looking fired. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to recommend you use [**`Vector drawables`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources).

> The major advantage of using a vector drawable is image scalability.
>   It can be scaled without loss of display quality, which means the same
>   file is resized for different screen densities without loss of image
>   quality.

Vector drawables allow you to replace multiple **`png/jpg/jpeg`** assets with a single vector graphic, defined in XML.

FYI- For responsive Textsize issue, You should use [**`SDP`**](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

Comment: it is not what I want. In addition to ImageView, If I galaxy s9 and nexus 5 textview font size to 15sp , galaxy s9's text is shown well, but the nexus 5's text is cut off even though they are same xxhdpi but have different screen size. I know why this happens. same dpi doesn't mean  they are same screen size.But I want to know how to solve this.

Comment: is the sdp used at actual service?

Comment: @Charles `actual service` means? Its responsive

Comment: I have one more question. As following your recommendation, I have to add dimension in  dimension. For example, the setting layout at using sdp is `android:textSize="@dimen/_70sdp"`. But I want to this `android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"`.

Comment: @Charles I didn't try this approach.

Comment: @Charles yes, you can.

Comment: I tried using available height like this "layout-h600dp". I calculated my height dp using ` windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics) displayMetrics.heightPixels/displayMetrics.density ` And got the result 592dp. So I tried using layout-h590dp but it didn't work. I added layout-h550dp and it worked. I don't understand my phone height  is 592dp and worked at 550dp, not at 590dp

Comment: do u understand what I mean?